# debug request timing using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, cakephp, profile

Good Morning - Can someone point me to a good resource that would help me understand what's going on in a Chrome debug sources graph?

I want to understand what is going on during that big space of time between kendo.all.min.js and cake.generic.css.

Neither the apache logs nor the php logs give any hints.

I'm not looking for an answer necessarily, just what tools to troubleshoot the latency.

CakePHP 2.6.2, Kendo UI PHP (trial), Xamp 3.2.1

Comment: You should start with the Inspect Debugging tools that comes with Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser load resource files (Javascript, CSS, images, etc.), for latency inspecting, you press <kbd>F12</kbd>, choose `Network`, press and hold to see `Latency` timeline.

[image]

(open screenshot image in a new windows for big size)

Comment: Thank you Do Nhu Vy. Very helpful.